# How can i Ajax this file upload in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm new to the topic of AJAX and I want to AJAX this file upload in rails. It's a nested file upload so be wary. When a photo is uploaded I just want it to show the photo and have a delete link.

I tried to follow the railscast on the topic but it didn't talk about file upload and was a little confusing. So **ANY** sort of advice would be awesome!

**new product page(HAML)**

```
 = form_for @product,:url => products_path, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f|
   -
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to take a look at this, http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/